# How to extend class with implicit parameter in Scala

Tags: scala, implicit-parameters

class B(implicit imp: Int)
  extends AC {
}

object C extends B{

}

Error: could not find implicit value for parameter imp

This is what i was looking for: [How to provide default value for implicit parameters at class level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12767074/how-to-provide-default-value-for-implicit-parameters-at-class-level)

Comment: Since object does not have a constructor it cannot be done. But you can have a class extending the other class `class B(implicit imp: Int)  extends A(imp)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scala> class B(implicit imp:Int)
defined class B

scala> class C extends B()(1)
defined class C

scala> implicit val imp:Int = 2
imp: Int = 2

scala> class D extends B
defined class D

scala>
```

Answer (score 5):

You extend it like you extend a class with non-implicit parameters, but you need an empty parameter list first:

```
scala> object C extends B()(5) {}
defined module C
```